# SOCKS communication using .net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, .net-4.0, socks

I want to communicate with server to run my c# application and so I need to connect with server through sock communication. Is it possible using .net framework 4 ?

Comment: Do you mean SOCKS (proxy server) or [BSD] sockets?

Comment: The answer is no :-) If you want to use TOR, and i guess so, you need a forwarding proxy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Socks and Sockets are different ..
Indeed if you wish to use sockets you could use System.Net.Sockets but,
       if you wish to use SOCKS (SOCKS client/server that can be used to provide convenient and secure network connectivity) you could use next example http://www.cknotes.com/?p=204

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class to connect to port on a remote server.

If you are looking for SOCKS C# libs you could go for these which works with HTTP, Socks4, Socks4a, and Socks5 proxy servers and comes with integrated help. It also works with Mono.

http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/starksoftproxyc/

Comment: As of Sep 30, 2012, the Starksoft Link is dead and, near as I can tell, the Sourceforge project doesn't have any files downloadable.

Comment: Edit: Managed to find what seems to be a cached copy here: https://bitbucket.org/Vhab/starksoft.net.proxy/src

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for same thing and ran across this:  [Socks4/5 proxy in .net](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/)

It isn't .net 4.0 but it is a good jumping off point.1